# Error when delete a node from the start in Doubly LinkedList

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I have a class that have insert, delete and printAll method. The error is when i delete a node from the first node and insert a node again it looks like the chains broken.
. For example numbers inserted are 12, 67, 55, 23, 6, when i delete 12, and insert a new node again (-999), the output will be 12, -999. why is that?

[image: see image]

```
public class Doubly {

    private Node head;
    private Node tail;
    private int countNode = 0;

    public class Node {

        int data;
        Node next;
        Node prev;

        public Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
            this.prev = null;
        }
    }

    public void insert(int data) {
        Node node = new Node(data);
        if (this.head == null) {
            this.head = this.tail = node;
        } else {
            tail.next = node;
            node.prev = tail;
            tail = node;
            tail.next = null;
        }
        this.countNode++; 
    }

    public void delete(int pos) {
        if (head == null) {
            return;
        }
        Node node = head;
        int count = 0;
        if (pos == 0) {
            this.head = node.next;
            this.tail = node.next;
            node.next = null;
        } else if (pos == this.countNode - 1) {
            Node oldTail = tail;
            tail = tail.prev;
            tail.next = null;
            oldTail.prev = null;
        } else {
            while (count < pos - 1) {
                node = node.next;
                count++;
                if (node == null || node.next == null) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            Node middleNode = node.next;
            node.next = middleNode.next;
            middleNode.next.prev = node;
            middleNode.prev = null;
            middleNode.next = null;
        }
        this.countNode--;
    }

    public void printAll() {
        Node node = this.head;
        while (node != null) {
            System.out.print(node.data + " ");
            node = node.next;
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

}
```

Comment: `insert` "looks ok", `delete` is (obviously) wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the error is in your delete method, specifically in the scenario when you are deleting the element at `pos` 0.

Let’s look at what your list structure is after all of your inserts:

```
null <- 12 -> 67
12 <- 67 -> 55
67 <- 55 -> 23
55 <- 23 -> 6
23 <- 6 -> null

Head -> 12
Tail -> 6
```

Now, let’s go through the steps in removing the element at position 0:

1. `Node node = this.head`. So we store the `12` node in `head`.
2. `this.head = node.next`. We are now setting the `head` node to the `next` of `node` which will be `67`
3. `this.tail = node.next`. This is where it starts going wrong. `node` is still the `12` node. We are thus setting the `tail` node to the node that follows `12` which is again `67`.
4. `node.next = null`. Finally, we are setting the `next` of the `12` node to null

Now if we look at the data structure again, we see:

```
null <- 12 -> null
12 <- 67 -> 55
67 <- 55 -> 23
55 <- 23 -> 6
23 <- 6 -> null

Head -> 67
Tail -> 67
```

And when you call the insert function, it sets the next of the tail node to the new node. Thus we end up with:

```
null <- 12 -> null
12 <- 67 -> -999
67 <- 55 -> 23
55 <- 23 -> 6
23 <- 6 -> null
67 <- -999 -> null

Head -> 67
Tail -> -999
```

And when you call `printAll`, you find that it prints the `head`, `67`, followed by it’s `next` which is now `-999` and then halts (`-999`’s `next` is `null`)